# PIL fill background image repeatedly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a small background image like this:

[image]

it's a smaller than my image size, so I need to draw it repeatedly. (think about background-repeat in css)

I searched a lot and can't find a solution to this....thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647311/how-to-merge-images-using-python-pil-library). It shows how to marge small images into bigger one.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the code linked to by Marcin, this will tile a background image on a larger one:

```
from PIL import Image

# Opens an image
bg = Image.open("NOAHB.png")

# The width and height of the background tile
bg_w, bg_h = bg.size

# Creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 1000 by 1000
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (1000,1000))

# The width and height of the new image
w, h = new_im.size

# Iterate through a grid, to place the background tile
for i in xrange(0, w, bg_w):
    for j in xrange(0, h, bg_h):
        # Change brightness of the images, just to emphasise they are unique copies
        bg = Image.eval(bg, lambda x: x+(i+j)/1000)

        #paste the image at location i, j:
        new_im.paste(bg, (i, j))

new_im.show()
```

Produces this:

[image: 1.png]

Or removing the `Image.eval()` line:

[image: 2.png]