# Tiling images by batch using python PIL, fill background image repeatedly by folder

Tags: python, concatenation, python-imaging-library, batch-processing

```
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

# Opens an image
bg = Image.open('./images/1.jpg')

# The width and height of the background tile
bg_w, bg_h = bg.size

# Creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 1000 by 1000
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (7000,9240))

# The width and height of the new image
w, h = new_im.size

# Iterate through a grid, to place the background tile
for i in range(0, w, bg_w):
    for j in range(0, h, bg_h):
        # Change brightness of the images, just to emphasise they are unique copies
        # bg = Image.eval(bg, lambda x: x+(i+j)/1000)

        #paste the image at location i, j:
        new_im.paste(bg, (i, j))

new_im.save('./tiled/tiled-image1.png')
```

Been using the code above from:
[PIL fill background image repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155087/pil-fill-background-image-repeatedly)

Now Im trying to make it per folder instead of doing the images one by one.
But can't make my code (below) to work. Could anyone help?

```
from PIL import Image


path = "./images/"

# Opens an image
bg = Image.open(path)

# The width and height of the background tile
bg_w, bg_h = bg.size

# Creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 1000 by 1000
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (7000,9240))



# The width and height of the new image
w, h = new_im.size

# Iterate through a grid, to place the background tile
for i in range(0, w, bg_w):
    for j in range(0, h, bg_h):
        # Change brightness of the images, just to emphasise they are unique copies
        # bg = Image.eval(bg, lambda x: x+(i+j)/1000)

        #paste the image at location i, j:
        new_im.paste(bg, (i, j))

new_im.save("./tiled/" + new_im + ".png")
new_im.show()
```

For sure I am missing something to run the code and get images in the folder but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk` to iterate over your folders and subfolders:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

INPUT_DIR = r'c:\so\69804229\images'
OUTPUT_DIR = r'c:\so\69804229\results'
IMAGE_EXT = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(INPUT_DIR):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(IMAGE_EXT):
            image_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            bg = Image.open(image_path)
            bg_w, bg_h = bg.size
            new_im = Image.new('RGB', (7000, 9240))
            w, h = new_im.size
            for i in range(0, w, bg_w):
                for j in range(0, h, bg_h):
                    new_im.paste(bg, (i, j))
            new_im.save(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, file))
```

Comment: it works, thanks!