# Stitch images together from html

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-stitching

This website has a large image combrised of 132 images, I want to find a way to stitch them together into a single image.  I know some python if anyone has a clue where to start.

http://www.mapytatr.net/PRODUKTY/MAPY_TAT/WYSOKIE/SLICES/wys_ii.htm

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge images using python PIL library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647311/how-to-merge-images-using-python-pil-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget `Python` - use `ImageMagic` (http://www.imagemagick.org/)

`+append` to create row

```
convert tpn_1.jpg tpn_2.jpg tpn_3.jpg +append row_1.jpg
```

`-append` to create column

```
convert row_1.jpg row_2.jpg row_3.jpg -append final.jpg
```

You can try also `montage` (from `ImageMagic` too) to get all in one command

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x3 tpn_* final.jpg
```

---

BTW: on Linux you can download all images using `wget` and `for` in `bash`

```
for i in $(seq 132); do echo "http://www.mapytatr.net/PRODUKTY/MAPY_TAT/WYSOKIE/SLICES/tpn_$i.jpg"; done | wget -i -
```

[image: kochane tatry]

kochane tatry :)