# matplotlib: merge 2 pdfs to one side-by-side

Tags: python, pdf

I have 2 different pdf plots (generated by matplotlib also) and I'd like to combine them as one side-by-side. Originally I wanted to generate with 2 subplots 121 and 122 but then was too tricky to adjust many details. So I generated two independent plots.

Is there any way to import those ready pdfs and just make one out of them? Because at the end in a latex file which I am using, it is much easier to deal with one figure file rather than two!

Comment: I actually think this is something that's easier to do in LaTeX using [subfigures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats).

Comment: I agree with @RogerFan. It is usually much better to use `subfigure` in latex, so that you also have two separate subcaptions.

Comment: I agree that many times it is easier and I have used subfigure routinely also. For this particular case, I wanted to use just one figure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Linux or Mac, the [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) program can do it.

```
    pdfjam --nup 2x1 leftFig.pdf rightFig.pdf --outfile combinedFig.pdf
```

Comment: this is very handy! My favorite command line for dealing with pdf was/is pdftk but this seems to be more advanced. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would save the plots as PNGs and then create a PDF out the PNGs using ReportLab. For example:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

c = canvas.Canvas('report.pdf', pagesize=letter)    

c.drawImage('filename1.png', 0,0)
c.drawImage('filename2.png', 0,100)

c.save()
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20150111073718/http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/pdfgen.html

Or if you're set on merging multiple PDFs than that's already been answered here: [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files) or you can merge image directly using PIL see here: [How do you merge images into a canvas using PIL/Pillow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647311/how-to-merge-images-using-python-pil-library).