# How to convert list of figures to long png in Python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, png, wand

I have a list of matplotlib figures and I'm wondering if there's any way to concatenate them into a single long png file. I have tried experimenting with MagickWand but it doesn't seem like there is a way to input figures as a `canvas.Image`.

As well I have tried creating a pdf with `reportlab` and then try to interpret with `wand` but every time I try to open up `wand.image.Image(filename=pdf_file_name)` in the console, it prints `None` to the output.

Is there anything that I am overlooking, and/or is there a better way to do this. Preferably this is a PNG file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647311/how-do-you-merge-images-using-pil-pillow)

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I am using PDF files, not jpg or png files as the input. Moreover, PIL doesn't fully support PDF files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all the figures are contained within a single PDF, you can use [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) to iterate over each page & append them to a single PNG image. This technique can be modified for multiple figures as needed.

```py
from wand.image import Image

pdf_file='/path/to/figures.pdf'

# Read figures
with Image(filename=pdf_file) as figures:
  # Create blank image with the dimensions of all pages/figures
  with Image(width= figures.width,
             height=figures.height*len(figures.sequence)) as canvas:
    top=0                            # Position offset
    for page in figures.sequence:    # Iterate over each page in figures
      canvas.composite(page, 0, top) # Composite page on to canvas
      top += page.height             # Adjust offset
   canvas.save(filename="out.png")   # Write out long png
```