# Color diffusion when merging multiple images in a folder using PIL in python

Tags: python-3.x, image, merge, python-imaging-library

I have set of 17 images and one of them has a highlighted pixel for my use. But, when I merge these 17 images, I get the color but it diffuses out of the pixel boundaries and I start seeing some colored pixel in black background.

I am using PIL library for the merging. I am attaching my code and the images for the reference. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Cretaing the Pixel array 

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor

img_path = '/Volumes/MY_PASSPORT/JRF/cancer_genome/gopal_gen/png_files/'

image_list = []
for entry in os.listdir(img_path):
    if entry.endswith('.png'):
        entry = int(entry.rstrip('.csv.png'))
        image_list.append(entry)
        image_list.sort()
list_img = []
for j in range(len(image_list)):
    stuff = str(image_list[j])+'.csv.png'
    list_img.append(stuff)
#print(list_img[0])

images = [Image.open(img_path+x) for x in list_img]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)
    #print(total_width, max_height)
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))
x_offset = 0
for im in images:
    new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
    #print(im.size)
    x_offset += im.size[0]
    #print(x_offset)
    new_im.save(img_path+'final_result_image.jpg')
```

Here is the combined image:
The third column has a pixel highlighted.

[image]

Here is the zoomed in part with the problem.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I was not active here for a while. But, It helped. Thanks @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JPEG` format is lossy - it is allowed to change your pixels to make the file smaller. If your image is a conventional photo of a real-life scene, this doesn't normally matter. If your data is a blocky, computer-generated image, or a set of classes from a classification process, it can go horribly wrong if you use `JPEG`.

So, the answer is to use `PNG` (or potentially `TIFF`) format for images that need to be lossless.

Comment: I have one more doubt. Say, if I have a fixed width of big image and I only want to keep pasting images in different columns (like pic above) till the max width is reached and then paste rest of the columns below in a second row. How can I do that?

Comment: Like image grid.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks. Anyone looking for image grid problem can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647311/how-do-you-merge-images-into-a-canvas-using-pil-pillow and https://keestalkstech.com/2020/05/plotting-a-grid-of-pil-images-in-jupyter/